# mod_fcgid: read timeout from pipe & End of script output before headers | Using powershell to fetch page via cron

Tags: windows, apache, powershell, cron, fastcgi

I am unable to solve this recurring issue i find in my apache logs.

The only thing that triggers this is the cronjob i have made using powershell to fetch a php file and i think it has something to do with powershell not closing the connection after visiting the page.

My powershell looks like this : `@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -Command "Invoke-WebRequest http://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron"
EXIT`

If i manually visit the wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron with my browser i do not see this message in the apache logs. Any ideas how to make powershell close the connection after file has been fetched?

If needed this is my fcgi confiugration in httpd.conf but like i said the error message only comes from the cronjob!

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
<IfModule fcgid_module>
    FcgidInitialEnv PATH "C:/Webserver/PHP;C:/WINDOWS/system32;C:/WINDOWS;C:/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem;"
    FcgidInitialEnv SystemRoot "C:/Windows"
    FcgidInitialEnv SystemDrive "C:"
    FcgidInitialEnv TEMP "C:/Webserver/PHP/TEMP"
    FcgidInitialEnv TMP "C:/Webserver/PHP/TEMP"
    FcgidInitialEnv windir "C:/WINDOWS"
    FcgidIOTimeout 500
    FcgidConnectTimeout 500
    FcgidBusyTimeout 500
    FcgidBusyScanInterval 500
    FcgidErrorScanInterval 500
    FcgidErrorScanInterval 500
    FcgidIdleScanInterval 500
    FcgidIdleTimeout 500
    FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
    FcgidZombieScanInterval 5000
    FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 10000
    FcgidMaxProcesses 20
    FcgidMaxRequestLen 12131072
    # Location php.ini:
    FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "C:/Webserver/PHP"
    FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 4000

    <Files ~ "\.php$">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI 
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php
        FcgidWrapper "C:/Webserver/PHP/php-cgi.exe" .php
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

All tips welcome, thank you!

Comment: Tried using wget instead same issue, so i guess it has nothing to do with powershell, it's probably windows tash scheduler that doesn't exit the job, i've even set it to "stop the task if it runs longer than 1 minute" but still getting the errors.

Comment: Found the issue, it was directly related to the configuration of FCGI i posted above. I lowered a lot of values and the errors have seemingly disappeared, i think it was the timeout values being to high.

Comment: Care to post an updated version? I'm having the same issue with the default config provided and looking for hints where to start modifying.